# Need to double click element to load query

Tags: jquery

I have this issue where I need to double click an image to load a query, I am doing an inventory website for fallout and I have the crafting benches as images and need to load items when certain benches is clicked but it gives me the value of the bench when I click once but then doesn't load the items for that crafting bench , I then need to click again before it loads. The items loads from a database where I call them through sql query when the crafting bench image is pressed.

```
    <form method="post" asp-page-handler="location" >
          <input id="station"  name="station" type="text" value="" >
          <input id="location" name="location" type="text" value="" >
    <div class="craftingbenchcon">

        <div class="Workbench Armour" onclick="document.forms[0].submit()">
            <img class="Workbenchimg" src="~/images/ArmourWorkbench.png" 
              alt="Workbenchimg"/> 
            <h3 class="workbenchname">Armour Workbench</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="Workbench Weapons" onclick="document.forms[0].submit()">
            <img class="Workbenchimg" src="~/images/WeaponsWorkbench.png" 
             alt="Workbenchimg"/> 
            <h3 class="workbenchname">Weapons Workbench</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="Workbench Tinker" onclick="document.forms[0].submit()">
            <img class="Workbenchimg" src="~/images/TinkerWorkbench.png" 
             alt="Workbenchimg"/>
            <h3 class="workbenchname">Tinker Workbench</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="Workbench Chemistry" onclick="document.forms[0].submit()">
            <img class="Workbenchimg" src="~/images/ChemestryStation.png" 
             alt="Workbenchimg"/>
            <h3 class="workbenchname">Chemestry Station</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="Workbench Cooking" onclick="document.forms[0].submit()">
            <img class="Workbenchimg" src="~/images/CookingStation.png" alt="Workbenchimg"/> 
            <h3 class="workbenchname">Cooking Station</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="Workbench Brewing" onclick="document.forms[0].submit()">
            <img class="Workbenchimg" src="~/images/BrewingStation.png" alt="Workbenchimg"/> 
            <h3 class="workbenchname">Brewing Station</h3>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="locationTabCrafting ">

        <div  class="backpacktabCrafting locationtabbtn"  
               onclick="document.forms[0].submit()">
         <label>Backpack</label>
            <img class="locationimg" src="~/images/backpack.webp" alt="location"/>      
        </div>


        <div   class="basetabCrafting " onclick="document.forms[0].submit()">
         <label>Base</label>
            <img class="locationimg" src="~/images/base.webp" alt="location"/>  
            
        </div>

        <div  class="SurvivaltenttabCrafting " onclick="document.forms[0].submit()">
         <label>Survival Tent</label>
            <img class="locationimg" src="~/images/survivaltent.webp" alt="location"/>  
        
        </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

```
    $(document).ready(function() {


        $(".Weapons").click(function () {
        localStorage.setItem("station", "WeaponsWorkbench");  
        });

        $(".Tinker").click(function () {
        localStorage.setItem("station", "TinkerWorkbench");  
        });

        $(".Chemistry").click(function () {
        localStorage.setItem("station", "ChemistryStation");  
        });

        $(".Cooking").click(function () {
        localStorage.setItem("station", "CookingStation");  
        });

         $(".Brewing").click(function () {
         localStorage.setItem("station", "BrewingStation");  
         });

        $(".Armour").click(function () {
        localStorage.setItem("station", "ArmourWorkbench");  
        });

       let getstation = localStorage.getItem("station");
       console.log(getstation)




      if(getstation == "ArmourWorkbench"){
      $(".Weapons").css("opacity", "30%");
      $(".Tinker").css("opacity", "30%");
      $(".Chemistry").css("opacity", "30%");
      $(".Cooking").css("opacity", "30%");
      $(".Brewing").css("opacity", "30%");
      $(".Armour").css("opacity", "100%");

      document.getElementById('station').setAttribute('value', 
      localStorage.getItem('station'));

      }else if(getstation == "WeaponsWorkbench"){
      $(".Weapons").css("opacity", "100%");
      $(".Tinker").css("opacity", "30%");
      $(".Chemistry").css("opacity", "30%");
      $(".Cooking").css("opacity", "30%");
      $(".Brewing").css("opacity", "30%");
      $(".Armour").css("opacity", "30%");

        document.getElementById('station').setAttribute('value', 
        localStorage.getItem('station'));

      }else if(getstation == "TinkerWorkbench"){
      $(".Weapons").css("opacity", "30%");
      $(".Tinker").css("opacity", "100%");
      $(".Chemistry").css("opacity", "30%");
      $(".Cooking").css("opacity", "30%");
      $(".Brewing").css("opacity", "30%");
      $(".Armour").css("opacity", "30%");
        document.getElementById('station').setAttribute('value', 
        localStorage.getItem('station'));

      }else if(getstation == "ChemistryStation"){
      $(".Weapons").css("opacity", "30%");
      $(".Tinker").css("opacity", "30%");
      $(".Chemistry").css("opacity", "100%");
      $(".Cooking").css("opacity", "30%");
      $(".Brewing").css("opacity", "30%");
      $(".Armour").css("opacity", "30%");
        document.getElementById('station').setAttribute('value', 
        localStorage.getItem('station'));

      }else if(getstation == "CookingStation"){
      $(".Weapons").css("opacity", "30%");
      $(".Tinker").css("opacity", "30%");
      $(".Chemistry").css("opacity", "30%");
      $(".Cooking").css("opacity", "100%");
      $(".Brewing").css("opacity", "30%");
      $(".Armour").css("opacity", "30%");
        document.getElementById('station').setAttribute('value', 
        localStorage.getItem('station'));

      }else if(getstation == "BrewingStation"){
      $(".Weapons").css("opacity", "30%");
      $(".Tinker").css("opacity", "30%");
      $(".Chemistry").css("opacity", "30%");
      $(".Cooking").css("opacity", "30%");
      $(".Brewing").css("opacity", "100%");
      $(".Armour").css("opacity", "30%");
        document.getElementById('station').setAttribute('value', 
        localStorage.getItem('station'));

    }


    //onclick for location buttons/ for styling
    $(".backpacktabCrafting").click(function () {
    localStorage.setItem("active", 1);  

    });
    //onclick for location buttons/ for styling
    $(".basetabCrafting").click(function () {
    localStorage.setItem("active", 2);  
    });
    //onclick for location buttons/ for styling
    $(".SurvivaltenttabCrafting").click(function () {
    localStorage.setItem("active", 3);  
    });

    let activeclass = localStorage.getItem("active");
    console.log(activeclass)



    if(activeclass == 1){
         $(".backpacktabCrafting").addClass("locationtabbtn");
             $(".basetabCrafting").removeClass("locationtabbtn");
    $(".SurvivaltenttabCrafting").removeClass("locationtabbtn");
        document.getElementById('location').setAttribute('value', 1);
    }else if(activeclass == 2){
         $(".basetabCrafting").addClass("locationtabbtn");
             $(".backpacktabCrafting").removeClass("locationtabbtn");
    $(".SurvivaltenttabCrafting").removeClass("locationtabbtn");
            document.getElementById('location').setAttribute('value', 2);
    }else if(activeclass == 3){
         $(".SurvivaltenttabCrafting").addClass("locationtabbtn");
             $(".basetabCrafting").removeClass("locationtabbtn");
    $(".backpacktabCrafting").removeClass("locationtabbtn");
            document.getElementById('location').setAttribute('value',3);
    }

    });
```

Comment: Please don't add irrelevant tags to your questions. If you feel that the C# and SQL tags _are_ relevant, please edit your question to show the C# code/SQL query you believe to be faulty and explain what leads you to this conclusion (though this might mean that your Javascript code is no longer relevant).

Comment: My C# and  SQL is working and doing what it is suppose to,  the issue is that I need to click twice on the image for the query to run. Sorry for the confusion about the tags still new .

Comment: You'll find your code easier to read/maintain if (a) indent code properly - most IDEs (include stack overflow snippet editor) have an auto-format button.  (b) don't mix js/jquery events with onclick=.  `onclick="document.forms[0].submit()"` will reload the form and *reset* your page (I that's guess why you have all that localStage code).

Comment: do not use two different handlers for the same event. Remove the onClick inline javascript and keep only the jquery ones. Add there what you had in the inline js. This double event binding can be what leads to the issue